# Debugging Angular application with Intellij Typescript debugger

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug an Angular application from Intellij 2021. So I'm using Intellij's Typescript and Javascript debuggers.

My OS is Ubuntu. Node.js version v16.14.2.

I'm following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2gboBOoc88). But I think that my project structure is different. In the video they seem to have two separate projects: a Java project for the back end, and an Angular project for the front end.

In my case both ends are in one project: It's a Java project in which the Angular project is in a folder within the Java project. I start both projects by `sbt run` from the Java project root.

And then Angular listens on port 4200, Java listens on port 9000.

So for debugging the Angular project, I start both projects with `sbt run`. I do it because I want the Java project to start.

According to the video, I now have to do in another terminal, from the Angular folder, `npm start`.

But wait! That would try to start another Angular project on Angular's default port 4200, to which another Angular process is already listening. So I do instead: `npm start -- --port 4201`. And accordingly I change the URL in the intellij's JavaScript Debug configuration to `http://localhost:4201`.

The Browser I chose in that configuration was Chrome, and I gave it the Chromium installation path.

Now, according to the video, when `npm start -- --port 4201` is completed, I can start the debugger by clicking the green debug button.

But it does not work.  After a few seconds I'm getting the message:

> Waiting for connection to localhost: 39807.
>
> Please ensure that the browser was started successfully with remote
> debugging port opened. Port cannot be opened if Chrome having the same
> User Data Directory is already launched.

[image]

I don't know where "39807" came from. In Intellij's `settings > debugger > built-in server` the port specified is a different number.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> According to the video, I now have to do in another terminal, from the Angular folder, npm start.But wait! That would try to start another Angular project on Angular's default port 4200, to which another Angular process is already listening

If your Angular app is already started with `sbt run` and listening on port 4200, I can see no reason for starting another server with `npm start`; just use the  **JavaScript Debug** configuration with your app URL you normally use to access it in browser (`http://localhost:4200` or whatever it looks like)

> After a few seconds I'm getting the message

Please make sure that no Chrome instances are running when you start the debugger.
Also, is Chrome installed with snap? Debugging doesn't work with Chromium installed with snap due to permissions issues, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38511#focus=Comments-27-4472759.0-0 for more info/workaround.
You can try a different Chrome version per instructions at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap. This actually uses the chromium packages from the debian repository and not snap.